# ESP8266 01 WIFI module problem. No AT cmd & can't flash

Tags: module, arduino, wifi, esp8266

[image]

I just bought new ESP8266 wifi module 5 days ago and looks like below:

```
Black colour
No Ai Thinker text
No Ai Cloud text
Cost : 7~10 $
```

I have tried many ways/websites/advices to make it works but I got nothing.

None AT command works
Flash new firmware keeps fail
Blue light blinking tutorial works

Official websites that I have go through it's step but doesn't work:
Instructables
Github
Stackoverflow
Espressive 
Youtube
Thingspeak
Ubidots

I have start my dev on this esp since 4 days ago
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ESP8266-01 boards are not breadboard-direct friendly. You'll find it easiest to attach some female-male jumper cables on the appropriate pins.

To flash the chip, this is the pinout you'll need.

ESP01 (left) and FTDI (right)

```
CH_PD + VCC = 3.3V (aka VCC)
GND + GPIO0 = GND
RXD = TXD
TXD = RXD
```